# The limit of $\frac{x^2 + y^2 - x^{3}y^{3}}{ x^2 + y^2}$ as $(x,y)\to(0,0)$

Tags: calculus, limits, multivariable-calculus, continuity

I have formula: $$ f(x,y) = \frac{x^2 + y^2 - x^{3}y^{3}}{ x^2 + y^2}$$ 
and I have to find whether $ \lim_{(x,y) \rightarrow (0,0) }  f(x,y)$ exists .

My attempt was: 
(1) set $x=0$; then $f(0,y) = 1$, set $y=0$, then $f(x,0) =1$.
I concluded that this function probably has $L = 1$.

By applying the definition of limit in two variables, 
 if $0 < \sqrt{x^2+y^2 }< \delta $, then there exists $|(-xy)^3 + x^2 + y^2) / 2 - 1 |  < \beta$.

I simplified all the way up to 
$(|(xy)^3|/(x^2+y^2) ) < \beta $, then I hit the brick wall.

It appears that $(xy)^3$ is unbounded, and I can't simplify this for the life of me. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: sorry, I meant sqrt((x^2 + y^2) < ∂, in line 5.

Comment: If $\sqrt{x^2+y^2}<\delta$, then $|x|<\delta$ and $|y|<\delta$, so $|xy|^3<\delta^6$, so $|xy|^3$ *is* bounded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the polar coordinates $x=\rho\cos\left(\theta\right)
 $, $y=\rho\sin\left(\theta\right)
 $ we get $$\frac{x^{2}+y^{2}-x^{3}y^{3}}{x^{2}+y^{2}}=\frac{\rho^{2}-\rho^{6}\sin^{3}\left(\theta\right)\cos^{3}\left(\theta\right)}{\rho^{2}}
 $$ and so $$\lim_{\rho\rightarrow0^{+}}\frac{\rho^{2}-\rho^{6}\sin^{3}\left(\theta\right)\cos^{3}\left(\theta\right)}{\rho^{2}}=1.
 $$

Comment: can you tell me what I was doing wrong? I'd really like to know what I was doing wrong so I don't make the same mistake next time.

Comment: @mathlover In this type of limits the right approach is, usually, the use of the polar coordinates, because you can use the identity $\cos^{2}(\theta)+\sin^{2}(\theta)=1$. It is a standard trick.

Answer (score 0):

Use polar coordinates: $x=r\cos(\theta), y= r\sin(\theta), 0\leq \theta < 2\pi$.

Then we get, for $(x,y)\neq(0,0)$, that $f(x,y)=\frac{x^2+y^2-(xy)^3}{x^2+y^2}=1-\frac{(xy)^3}{x^2+y^2}=1-\frac{(r^2\cos(\theta)\sin(\theta))^3}{r^2}=1-r^4(\cos(\theta)\sin(\theta))^3\rightarrow 1$ when $r\rightarrow 0, \theta$ varies freely.

Comment: It is exactly what I wrote.

Comment: I know. I didn't see your anser when I posted mine. I think we posted roughly at the same time.